# Pass progress bar through async.series - nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, progress

Right im trying to get progress from a list of tasks run through async series

```
module.exports = update;

function update(){
  // Require Deps
  var async = require('async');
  var progress = require('progress);
  var tasks = [task1,task2,task3];

  // Create the progress bar using the list of tasks
  // as the length of the bar
  var bar = new progress(':current/:total [:bar] :task', {
    total: tasks.length
  });

  //Run async series using the array of tasks
  async.series(tasks,function(err,result){
    //  Do something with the results or errors
  })
};

var task1 = function(callback){
    callback();
};

var task2 = function(callback){
    callback();
}
```

This is a very simple version of my code.

**The Question**

How can i pass the bar to each of the functions or 'through' the functions and callbacks to that on success of each task im able to use

```
bar.tick({'task': tasks[bar.curr]});
```

everything i try I get bar not defined so tried passing bar into the functions with the callback function(callback, bar) and then i get tick not defined

Im new to nodeJs and well js all together so please be gentle

**NOTE** what im trying to achieve is to complete a list of functions displaying the current task in a progress bar
Ive read the docs and looked at the examples for progress and of async but still can;t make heads or tails of it

**Am I close or is there a better way**

Comment: You asked a question, why don't you upvote or accept any answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `bar.tick`, every time you want to update the current task in the taskbar. For example:

```
var task1 = function(callback){
    bar.tick({bar:'Finish First Task'})
    callback();
};
```

All your functions (task1,task2) should be declared INSIDE of `update` function, otherwise they will not be able to access the `bar` variable.

Comment: I know that I would need bar.tick to progress the bar not happy at having to have all of the functions inside of the update function though as eventually I want to generate the list of functions dynamically so append them all with one common name tasks.task1 tasks.task2 on the turn the tasks object into an array to run but I wanted the functions external so that new tasks could be added and asyncs task list would be automatically updated

Comment: can I not just use the bar variable as a global so it can be assesed by external functions ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure its the best solution, but when doing having callbacks and requesting a result, I have some kind of counter which I then check in my "final" callback:

i.e. have a global (before function update())

```
var tasksStatus = {task1:false,task2:false,task3:false};
```

and then in each task function set that

```
var task1 = function(callback){
   tasksStatus.task1 = true;
   callback();
};
```

Then you can check the global variable for which task is done and act accordingly.

Edit: a sample callback could be:

```
callback = function () {
   var status = 0;
   for(var s in tasksStatus) {
     if(tasksStatus[s]) 
        status += 33;
   }

   // update progress

   if(status == 99)  {
     // done....
   }
}
```

Comment: Would i then require another task to watch the array (taskStatus) for changes and one the event one of the values changes do a bar.tick() or process.tick()

Comment: the callback function can check taskstatus (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

It's little complicated, I'm sorry. What we doing is to make new function instead of the functions in the array. The new function we call the original function, and when the original function finish (callback), it will call the `progress.tick`, after that it will run the original callback function.

```
var tasks=[task1,task2,task3]

for (var i in tasks){
  (function(orgFunc,i){  // This Function will be run on task1,task2,task3. `i` will be 0,1,2, `orgFunc` will be the original function.
    tasks[i]=function(next){   // Replace the original function with new function
         orgFunc(funtion(){    // Call the original function
            bar.tick({bar:'Finish Task #' + i})                  
            next.apply(null,arguments)   // Call the callback.
         })
  }}).bind(null,tasks[i],i)
}
```